# Joint probability distribution with dependant domains

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given a joint distribution function with this specific domain:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = g(x,y)*1_{x,y\ge 0,\space x+y\le1}$$

I'd like to find the expected values of $X,Y$, i'm just unsure about the integral bounds:

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^{1-x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$$
$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^{1-y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$$
$$E(X)=\int_0^{1-y}xf_{X}(x)dx$$
$$E(Y)=\int_0^{1-x}yf_{Y}(y)dy$$

Are the integral bounds correct? Or does the expected value bounds should be from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two are correct. $EX$ and $EY$ are just numbers and they cannot involve variables. The correct formulas are $EX=\int_0^{1}xf_X(x)dx$ and $EX=\int_0^{1}yf_Y(y)dy$.  $X$ and $Y$ take all values from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: and if the domain was $0\le x\le y$ then what would $X$ and $Y$'s bounds were in the expected value? $0$ to $\infty$ ?

Comment: @CodeHoarder Yes, that is right.

Comment: thank you, one last question: if i want to check if the function integrates to one over the domain, the integral would be: $\int_0^{1}\int_0^{1-y}g(x,y)dxdy=1$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right again.  @CodeHoarder

Comment: Sorry i have another thing that's bothering me,suppose i have $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ and i want to calculate $E(X|Y)$, that is actually a function of Y, so do the integral bounds change accordingly? meaning: $E(X|Y) = \int_0^{1-y}xf_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$. Can you please explain when the bounds should be over the whole domain and when on the dependent domain?